# Difference between get() and filter() of python django? Does filter() does not consider associated table while fetch data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views

```
models.py
```

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfileImg', default='ProfileImg/default-avatar.png')
    feedback = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
```

`views.py`

While using objects.get()

```
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        user.userprofile.feedback = sentiment_Value 
        user.save()
```

it is working fine.

but while using objects.filter()

```
 user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id)
 user.userprofile.feedback = sentiment_Value 
 user.save()
```

I'm getting error

```
user.userprofile.feedback = sentiment_Value
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'userprofile'
```

and the `user` returns

```
user: <QuerySet [<User: snegi8005>]>
```

**I don't know why this is happening. I thought both get() and filter() function work same the only difference is get() raises exception if nothing found and filter() return none if no match found.**

how get() and filter() works?

Please correct me if i'm wrong and help me solving this.

i want to get the user's data of a user.id and the associated table `userprofile` data also. in case data not found it should return none or should not raise exception.
I know i can use get() with try/except block but that would be too much of code for me.

Comment: `get` gets a single item (and raises an exception if there are not exactly one). `filter` makes a subsetted queryset (actual evaluation is deferred)

Comment: `User.objects.filter(....).first()` might do what you want. If the queryset is empty, then `first()` will return `None` rather than raise an exception.

Comment: I would have posted it as an answer in order to give you more detail, but this question was closed on the grounds of a so-called "duplicate" which did not in fact answer your question of how to get the object or `None` without using "too much code" (such as writing a try/except block).

Comment: @alani  I  figure it out just now . thanx for that. but one more thing to ask. if my queryset contains only one row data then why i need to use .first().

Comment: Because the result of `filter` is still a QuerySet, not an individual object **even if there is only one**. And in fact, it is probably not even evaluated at that point (so the number of results is unknown until it is needed) - the actual search of the database happens when you try to extract objects from it e.g. by calling `first()`